# How to define the culture that the XmlSerializer uses

Tags: c#, localization, xml-serialization

I am deserializing a xml-configuration file using the following code:

```
// Create object by deserializing the given xml document
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConfigurationFile));
var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var configFile = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

In the configuration I have some floating numbers defined as following:

> DailyThreshold="41.9"

As the decimal separator "." is culture dependent I am wondering how I can define the culture the serializer uses to parse these numbers?

Comment: It's a really *good* idea to save configuration in the neutral culture. `XmlSerializer` does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `XmlSerializer` for both serializing and deserializing you have no reason to worry about culture: the serializer doesn't care about culture, neither it changes the serialized data in any way.

The data is alwasy serialized with the same format, which has nothing to do with any culture settings (nor UI culture, nor thread culture, nor any kind of culture).

#### Evidence in MSDN docs

I wrote this without looking for evidences simply because XML is a format for exchanging data between different systems and platforms, so the serialization format and deserialization parse must be equal in all the systems.

However, if you dive into MSDN docs, you can read this:

> The majority of the methods found in an XmlConvert class are used to convert data between strings and strongly-typed formats. Methods are locale independent. This means that they do not take into account any locale settings when doing conversion.

on [Conversion of XML Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15st98za(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried to found documentation on this on MSDN, but failed to find it. Is your answer based on documentation or observation?

Comment: It's difficult to find an evidence in MSDN, but I did.

Comment: What if I want to serialize using a culture though? Is there any way to do this / force this? I have a report viewer app on the other end that just reads straight XML values.

Comment: In serialization there is no such thing as culture. All values are serialized in a way similar to InvarinatCulture, so that they can be safely deserialized to the original value. I think that what you need is to convert the values to the desired string representation, and serialize an object with that representation. If there are not many cases, I'd use custom classes for your special representation of the data.

Comment: `The **majority** of the methods...` is not very reassuring

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj. Read again "methods are locale independent" (all) and "majority convert strings to strongly-typed" (some do other things)

Answer (score 2):

XmlSerializer class use the format configuration of your OS, it is configured in region section, in order your program uses a specific format, you could assign directly to the Thread, somenthing like below. For example if you live in a country of Latinoamerica is pretty common to use , insted of . that it is the standar representation.

```
//Write this code at the begining of the program 
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; //Force use . insted of ,
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```