# WPF App Support Locale without Localization

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, locale

I have a US English WPF app that isn't language localized but English-fluent users want it to run on PCs set to German locale. So displaying everything in English isn't the problem but they're seeing parse failures when my app reads from XML files. The XML files are manually created by developers as part of a plugin architecture and contain numbers formatted like 1.23E+05. I read them in with StreamReader and XmlSerializer.Deserialize(). Most fields in the serialized class are declared as strings and I later parse them into doubles. Is there a way to support this use model? Is there a solution that only impacts inputs from outside the app (hoping to minimize required changes)? I think what I'm asking for is to support different locales without fully supporting localization, if that makes sense. I'm okay with the locale affecting the format of how numbers/dates are displayed, if that happens auto-magically. My primary concern is to not crash :) Thank you.

Comment: When your app runs on a german pc you still want to use the english number/date/etc. format? Is that your goal?

Comment: @Mighty Badaboom: Updated the post to indicate no preference in how those are displayed.

Comment: What is in xml files? Normally, if it's settings or some internal data (as opposed to e.g. user generated reports) then they must be saved in neutral culture to avoid cases like this. How do you serialize/create xml and then deserialize/load/use it? `XmlSerializer` is [culture independent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21140292/1997232) (aka uses neutral culture from the box).

Comment: @Sinatr: Updated the post to describe the XML files a bit more.

Comment: You do not show how do you read xml files. It seems *other developers* are using neutral culture already, so it's your bug ^^.

Comment: @Sinatr. Updated the post to add more XML file info. I do not dispute that I'm doing or not doing something and thus causing the parse failures.

Comment: Can you create [repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (input xml, your code, error, etc). If you are using `XmlSerializer` and reading number `1.23E+05` as e.g. `double` there shouldn't be any problem disregards of current locale. You problem may be unrelated to xml (there is no evidence so far if it is so).

Comment: @Sinatr: You may be right. I'll work on a proper repro since the app is huge. I didn't realize it could work correctly out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly set the culture for your app

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

Instead of the InvariantCulture, you can also pass a specific culture. Things like number formats etc. are tied to your current culture.

Comment: So if I set CurrentCulture = en-US, then as along as all of my input files contain numbers formatted for en-US then it won't matter what the locale is of the machine I'm executing on?

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat trick described in the [post of Sebastien Lambla](https://serialseb.com/blog/2007/04/03/wpf-tips-1-have-all-your-dates-times/):

Insert into your `App.xaml.cs`-File

```
public partial class App : Application

{

    static App()

    {

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(

            typeof(FrameworkElement),

            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(

                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

    }

}
```

Now your application defaults to the current culture **on the client machine** and **at run time**.

The VB.Net-Variant is in the `Application.xaml.vb`-File

```
Class Application
    Public Sub New()

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            GetType(FrameworkElement),
            New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)))
    End Sub

End Class
```