# Regional settings and decimal point when deserializing from string

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization, decimal-point

My program is deserializing a "message" from string:

```
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(message))
{
    using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
        deserializedMessage = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my message string I have:

```
<value>593,384040</value>
```

While on dev machine where I built the software, I see that value in deserialized object is `593,38404` and is correctly saved to database, on integration server value ends up as `593384040`.

Is it possible that culture / regional settings are messing up deserialization? And if so, where should I solve it - in OS settings or in code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please include real message and also definition of `Message` class.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140292/how-to-define-the-culture-that-the-xmlserializer-uses.  It sounds to me like the integration is doing the "correct" thing (though I'm a little confused by what you're seeing locally). Are you sure the database column is the same type both locally and on the integration server, and that the value you're see when looking at the database isn't being formatted before being shown?

Comment: You need to add the code to the `Message` object. My best guess is the value is desirialized to a string and then parsed at the integration server. anyway, a value of "593,384040" *must* be parsed into 593384040 as per XML standard. There is no localized XML. All values use a decimal dot, not a comma in all cultures, since XML is culture-agnostic.

Comment: My guess is: on the integration server, the `comma` is being treated as _thousand separator_ rather than a _decimal separator_...

Comment: I'd suggest you use a **specific Culture** to serialize/deserialize. Otherwise it will always end up in such problems. If your dev machine uses a culture where the decimal sep. is "," and on the server it's for example en-US, then it will not be recognized as decimal sep. there. To avoid that, you could force to always use en-US when serializing/deserializing. Problem here seems to be the serialization, though. A floating point should be serialized to "12.345" always when using the default Methods of XmlSerializer. So somehow you seem to have forced the comma. Simply don't.

Comment: @IronGeek Not for the deserialization part. .NET would throw an `InvalidOperationException` because in `593,384040` the separator is placed wrong then.

Comment: @MiGro Depends ... if "value" is a string, then the deserializer will deserialize it as is. We do not know what happens in between deserialization and DB from the snippets given.

Comment: What happens if you switch from `XmlTextReader` to `XmlReader.Create(stringReader)`?  According to the [docs for `XmlTextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) *Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you use the System.Xml.XmlReader class instead.*